# linux - command or script to group files

Tags: linux, shell

Here is my folder structure , would prefer to have it grouped so that the md files are centralised

current - inside the root folder

```
account\business.md
account\changelog.md
account\feature.md
account\readme1.md

user\business.md
user\CHANGELOG.md
user\feature.md
user\readme2.md

kid\business.md
kid\changelog.MD
kid\feature.md
kid\help.md
```

expected output -

```
business\account.md (account\business.md is been put inside business folder as account.md)
business\user.md (user\business.md is been put inside business folder as user.md)
business\kid.md (kid\business.md is been put inside business folder as kid.md)

note :- the file names are case insensitive
changelog\account.md (account\changelog.md is been put inside business folder as account.md)
changelog\user.md (user\CHANGELOG.md is been put inside business folder as user.md)
changelog\kid.md (kid\changelog.MD is been put inside business folder as kid.md)

feature\account.md (account\feature.md is been put inside business folder as account.md)
feature\user.md (user\feature.md is been put inside business folder as user.md)
feature\kid.md (kid\feature.md is been put inside business folder as kid.md)

account\readme1.md (left as is , since no common match found)
user\readme2.md (left as is , since no common match found)
kid\help.md (left as is , since no common match found)
```

Comment: `find . -name '*.md'` , tried this to run to get the list of files , couldn't figure out how to group them and rename inside folders

Comment: You have 12 files, rename them with `mv`.  Or this is just a sample and you have a lot more?  Also, are you sure you are on Linux?  the directory separators are \ , like in Windows.  It should be `/`.

Comment: @Nic3500 - this is just a sample, the actual number of folders are around 200

Comment: and apologies for the \ to / , you are right ,  its running in linux